# how can we get multi count values from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a database table with these columns: `'dialogue', 'user_id',` and `'readed'`. I want to count unread messages for every dialogue.

**For example:**

```
select count(messageid) from messages where user_id = $id and readed=0 and diyalogid = $diyalog1

select count(messageid) from messages where user_id = $id and readed=0 and diyalogid = $diyalog2

select count(messageid) from messages where user_id = $id and readed=0 and diyalogid = $diyalog3
```

How can I calculate the count with just one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN diyalogid = $diyalog1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS diyalog1Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN diyalogid = $diyalog2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS diyalog2Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN diyalogid = $diyalog3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS diyalog3Count
FROM 
    messages 
WHERE
    user_id = $id 
    AND readed=0
```

**Edit**

To answer you comment. I am not really sure what you want. You could do this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS theCount,
    diyalogid
FROM 
    messages 
WHERE
    user_id = $id 
    AND readed=0
GROUP BY
    diyalogid
```

Then you will have a count per `diyalogid`

Comment: can we do it without $diyalog variables? so for every diyalogid values. it can be more like facebook message system.